# How are the control points connected in a NURBS surface?

Tags: maya, nurbs

I'm trying to learn how to deal with NURBS surfaces for a project. Basically I wan't to build a geometry in some 3D program with NURBS, then export the geometry, and run some simulations with it. I have figured out the NURBS curve, and I do think I mostly understand how surfaces work, but what I don't get is how the control points are connected. Apparently you don't need any topology matrix as with polygons? When I export NURBS surfaces from Maya, in the file format .ma, which is plain text file, I can see the knot vectors, and then just a list of points. No topology information. How does this work? How can you reconstruct the NURBS surface without knowing how the points are connected to each other? The exported file is written below:

```
//Maya ASCII 2013 scene
//Name: test4.ma
//Last modified: Sat, Jan 26, 2013 07:21:36 PM
//Codeset: UTF-8
requires maya "2013";
requires "stereoCamera" "10.0";
currentUnit -l centimeter -a degree -t film;
fileInfo "application" "maya";
fileInfo "product" "Maya 2013";
fileInfo "version" "2013 x64";
fileInfo "cutIdentifier" "201207040330-835994";
fileInfo "osv" "Mac OS X 10.8.2";
fileInfo "license" "student";
createNode transform -n "loftedSurface1";
    setAttr ".t" -type "double3" -0.68884794895562784 0 -3.8172687581953233 ;
createNode nurbsSurface -n "loftedSurfaceShape1" -p "loftedSurface1";
    setAttr -k off ".v";
    setAttr ".vir" yes;
    setAttr ".vif" yes;
    setAttr ".covm[0]"  0 1 1;
    setAttr ".cdvm[0]"  0 1 1;
    setAttr ".dvu" 0;
    setAttr ".dvv" 0;
    setAttr ".cpr" 4;
    setAttr ".cps" 4;
    setAttr ".cc" -type "nurbsSurface" 
        3 3 0 0 no 
        8 0 0 0 1 2 3 3 3
        11 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 6

    54
    0.032814107781307778 -0.01084889661073064 -2.5450696958149557
    0.032814107781308312 -0.010848896610730773 -1.6967131305433036
    0.032824475105651972 -0.010848896610730714 -0.0016892641735144487
    0.032777822146102309 -0.01084889661073018 2.5509821204222565
    0.032948882997777158 -0.010848896610730326 5.3256822304677218
    0.032311292550627417 -0.010848896610730283 7.5033561343333179
    0.034690593487551526 -0.010848896610730296 11.39484483093603
    0.014785648001686571 -0.010848896610730293 11.972583607988943
    -0.00012526283089935193 -0.010848896610730293 12.513351622510489
    0.87607723187763198 -0.023973071493875439 -2.5450696958149557
    0.87607723187766595 -0.023973071493876091 -1.6967131305433036
    0.87636198619878247 -0.023973071493875821 0.00026157734839016289
    0.87508059175355446 -0.023973071493873142 2.5441541750955903
    0.87977903805225144 -0.023973071493873861 5.3510431702524812
    0.86226664730269065 -0.02397307149387367 7.4087403205209448
    0.9276177640022375 -0.023973071493873725 11.747947146400762
    0.39164345444212556 -0.023973071493873704 12.72679599298271
    -0.003344290659457324 -0.023973071493873708 13.356608602511475
    2.7585407036097025 0.080696275184513055 -2.5450696958149557
    2.7979735813230628 0.036005680442686323 -1.6988092981025378
    2.7828331201271896 0.05438167150027777 0.0049374879309111996
    2.6143679292284574 0.23983328019207673 2.5309327393956176
    2.67593270347135 0.19013709747074492 5.3992530024698517
    2.5981387973985108 0.20347021966427298 7.2291224273514345
    2.8477496474469728 0.19983391361149261 12.418208886861429
    1.1034136098865515 0.20064198162322153 14.474560637904968
    -0.010126299867110311 0.20064198162322155 15.133224682698101
    4.5214126649737496 0.45953483463333544 -2.5450696958149557
    4.6561826938778452 0.23941045408996731 -1.7369291398229287
    4.6267725925384751 0.29043329565744253 0.025561242784985394
    3.9504978751410711 1.3815767918640129 2.5159293599869446
    4.1596851721552888 1.0891788615080038 5.438642765250469
    3.9992107014958198 1.1676270867254697 7.0865667556376426
    4.4319212871194775 1.1462321162116154 12.949041810935984
    1.6384310220676352 1.1509865541035829 15.927795222282771
    -0.015643773215464073 1.1509865541035829 16.578582772395933
    5.2193823159440154 3.0233786192453191 -2.5450696958149557
    5.2193823159440162 3.0233786192453196 -1.6967131305433036
    5.2218229691816047 3.0233786192453191 0.0091618497226043649
    5.2108400296124504 3.0233786192453196 2.5130032217858407
    5.251110808032692 3.0233786192453191 5.4667467111172652
    5.1010106339208772 3.0233786192453191 6.9770771103715621
    5.6611405519478906 3.0233786192453205 13.358896446133507
    2.0430537629341199 3.0233786192453183 17.059047057656215
    -0.019924192630756767 3.0233786192453191 17.6998820408444
    5.1365144716134976 5.4897102753589557 -2.5450696958149557
    5.1365144716134994 5.4897102753589566 -1.6967131305433036
    5.1389093836131625 5.4897102753589566 0.0089946049919694682
    5.1281322796146718 5.4897102753589566 2.5135885783430627
    5.1676483276091361 5.4897102753589548 5.4645725296190131
    5.0203612396297714 5.4897102753589566 6.9851884798073476
    5.5699935435527692 5.4897102753589566 13.328625149888618
    2.0133428487217855 5.4897102753589557 16.975388787391935
    -0.01960785732642523 5.4897102753589557 17.617014800296868

    ;
select -ne :time1;
    setAttr ".o" 1;
    setAttr ".unw" 1;
select -ne :renderPartition;
    setAttr -s 2 ".st";
select -ne :initialShadingGroup;
    setAttr ".ro" yes;
select -ne :initialParticleSE;
    setAttr ".ro" yes;
select -ne :defaultShaderList1;
    setAttr -s 2 ".s";
select -ne :postProcessList1;
    setAttr -s 2 ".p";
select -ne :defaultRenderingList1;
select -ne :renderGlobalsList1;
select -ne :hardwareRenderGlobals;
    setAttr ".ctrs" 256;
    setAttr ".btrs" 512;
select -ne :defaultHardwareRenderGlobals;
    setAttr ".fn" -type "string" "im";
    setAttr ".res" -type "string" "ntsc_4d 646 485 1.333";
select -ne :ikSystem;
    setAttr -s 4 ".sol";
connectAttr "loftedSurfaceShape1.iog" ":initialShadingGroup.dsm" -na;
// End of test4.ma
```

Answer (score 1):

A NURBS surface is allays topologically square with points of degree+spans in u direction and (degree-1)+spans+1* in v direction. (a single NURBS surface is like one face of a polygon only more complicated)

The first 2 attributes in ".cc" are the degree in direction, and the next two lines define the knots each individual value represents a span. Duplicates are just weights so the point is repeated x times so:

```
8 0 0 0 1 2 3 3 3
```

Means there 8 knots (in this case in U direction) with 0 1 2 3 spans for a total of 6 points so it's a single span curve of third degree in U direction. The example has 9 points in V direction thus 7*9 = 54 points in total

This is not enough however, for NURBS to be even remotely useful. You must implement trim curves which are curves that lay on the UV parametrization of the surface and they can clip the individual NURBS to different shape.

In practice however maya users rely on manual quilting. Quilts** are the higher order NURBS equivalent of a mesh, that most nurbs modelers use as a concept. To handle these its often not enough to have even the trim curves. As trim curves cannot be reliably transported between applications, without sewing. Thus many applications rely on actually telling what the spatial history of said surface to surface quilt collections topographical connection is. So be prepared to make your own intersection algorithms etc., etc., for any meaningful NURBS compatibility.

For more on the mathematical underpinning info see Wikipedia, wolfram etc.

* If I remember correctly something like that.

** Quilts have different names in different applications due to simultaneous discovery on in several different language areas.

Answer (score 0):

NURBS surfaces' CVs are always laid out in a grid.  The number of CVs in a nurbs surface can be computed using the degree of the surface and the number of knots in each direction.  Then the CVs are just presented in some specific order, typically row-major.

Let's look at your example.  I'm mostly just guessing the format, so you'll want to check my assumptions.

```
3 3 0 0 no
```

It looks like you have a bicubic surface. It's not periodic in either direction (that is, you have a sheet rather than a cylinder or torus). Your CVs are non-rational, meaning they're [x,y,z] instead of [xw,yw,zw,w].

In other words, the format of that first line appears to be:

```
[degree in s] [degree in t] [periodic in s] [periodic in t] [rational]
```

Next up, one knot vector has 8 knot values, and the other has 11.  For a degree 3 non-periodic nurbs, the number of CVs is num_knots - 2.  So, you have 6 x 9 CVs in this surface.

The first 6 CVs are in the first row.  The next 6 are in the next row, etc.

If you're looking for more information on NURBS, I'd recommend [this text](http://tom.cs.byu.edu/~557/text/cagd.pdf) for theory.  For maya specific stuff, they have some decent documentation in the maya API.