# Nurbs curve parameters in Maya?

Tags: maya, curve, nurbs

I get a Maya .ma file, I want to understand the parameters for nurbsCurve, the file has contents like this:

```
createNode nurbsCurve; # create a nurbsCurve
    setAttr -k off ".v"; # set attribute about knots?
    setAttr ".cc" -type "nurbsCurve"  # attribute setting 
        3 1 0 no 3
        6 0 0 0 1 1 1  
        4  # 4 stand for the below has 4 coordiniates
        7.82436 0.545707 8.54539
        7.86896 0.545707 9.61357
        7.28368 0.53563 9.8433
        6.06638 0.53563 9.89412
        ;
...
```

I don't understand what the line `3 1 0 no 3` and `6 0 0 0 1 1 1`  stands for, anybody understand what these lines stand for?

Comment: This could help: https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/Nodes/nurbsCurve.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I know so far, only the first three figures.
[3] [1] [0]
corresponds to:
[degree] [span] [index of the form: open/closed/periodic]

Comment: Also from here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14569233/3608824

I get to know `6 0 0 0 1 1 1`, means there're 6 knots with 0 1 spans, duplicates are just weights so the point is repeated x times so.